# POSTGRESQL COUNT() returning more

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this SQL statement:

```
select a.title, a.video_id, b.id
from
    tzrat_community_videos a
    inner join
    tzrat_video_views b on a.video_id = b.videoid
where
    b.cdate >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00' and
    b.cdate <= '2014-06-26 23:59:59' and
    a.video_id = 'dCflt1d2xPw' and
    a.published = 1 and b.duration != 0 and
    (
        (a.percent is not null and (100*b.seconds)/b.duration >= a.percent ) or
        ((100*b.seconds)/b.duration >= 80)
    )
    group by b.videoid, a.title, a.video_id, b.id
```

Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I649X.png

But I want to have only the title, video_id and the number of times it appears (I want the number of views this video have)
So , I make this statement:

```
select a.title, a.video_id, count(b.id) as views
from
    tzrat_community_videos a
    inner join
    tzrat_video_views b on a.video_id = b.videoid
where
    b.cdate >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00' and
    b.cdate <= '2014-06-26 23:59:59' and
    a.video_id = 'dCflt1d2xPw' and
    a.published = 1 and
    b.duration != 0 and
    (
        (a.percent is not null and (100*b.seconds)/b.duration >= a.percent ) or
        ((100*b.seconds)/b.duration >= 80)
    )
group by b.videoid, a.title, a.video_id
```

But this returns me this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD1zY.png

So... what am I doing wrong? is the same statement, just b.id -> count(b.id) as views

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, you group also by `b.Id`

What you don't do in the second case (of course, as it's in the aggregate function).

So change

```
count(b.id)
```

by

```
count(distinct b.id)
```

if you want to avoid duplicated `b.id` count.

Comment: @user3770536 no prob. Don't forget to accept the answer to "close this case" ;)